# Хранение пользовательских данных

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

Где лучше хранить данные пользователей (расчет на большое количество пользователей - больше 10.000 игроков)? **В базах данных** или **файлах**? (Есть бот на Node.JS, надо где-то хранить аккаунты игроков).

В чем их плюсы или минусы? Можно ли как-то выбирать несколько данных разных пользователей, чтобы сортировать, и т.д. (например: выбрать значения баланса двух разных игроков и их отсортировать?)

P.S Вопрос был переформулирован.

Comment: *MySQL или JSON?* Ну вот не надо сравнивать тёплое с мягким, да?

Comment: JSON - это не база данных. Лучше уж сравнить MySQL и MongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По имеющимся данным ответить на ваш вопрос невозможно. В одних случаях больше подойдут реляционные бд, в каких-то noSQL. Если у вас считается сложная статистика, ожидаются замысловатые связи жесткие отношения, то берите sql. Если мало какие данные из-вне объекта требуются для функционирования этого объекта - берите nosql

Answer (score 1):

Используй `sqlite`. Те же файлы, но обеспечивают доступ как к обычным базам данных.
Индексирование делает своё дело - обращение к данным и сортировка гораздо быстрее.

Кроме того, потом легче будет переделать на настоящую базу данных.